# What's the difference between a tuple and list in the python which one is more efficient

Tags: python, django, list, tuples, data-science

In my one of the interview the interview ask me about the tuple and the list in python. And ask which is more efficient in case of finding a element on both .

Answer (score 1):

The **major** difference between tuples and lists is that a list is **mutable**, whereas a tuple is **immutable**. This means that a list **can be changed**, but a tuple **cannot**.The contents in a list can be modified, edited or deleted  while the contents in a tuple are fixed and cannot be modified, edited or deleted.